# Why can't I add this entry to my dictionary?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, object, dictionary

I am attempting to make an application which gets and inputted URL via textbox, retrieves the HtmlCode of that website when a button is clicked and stores both in a dictionary which is then displayed in a listbox.

However, I haven't been able to implement any of it into the user interface yet due to having an issue when trying to add an entry to the dictionary. To retrieve the HtmlCode I am calling the method GetHtml however, i am getting an error when trying to add the website and the code to the dictionary.

Code Follows

```
namespace HtmlCheck
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

            var dict = new SortedDictionary<string, WebsiteInfo>();

            var list = (from entry in dict
                        orderby entry.Key
                        select entry.Key).ToList();

        }

        private static void addPerson(string websiteUrl)
        {
            dict.Add(websiteUrl, new WebsiteInfo { WebsiteUrl = websiteUrl, HtmlCode = getHtml(websiteUrl) });
        }

        private static SortedDictionary<string, WebsiteInfo> dict;

        public string getHtml(string websiteUrl)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                return client.DownloadString(websiteUrl);
        }
    }

    public class WebsiteInfo
    {
        public string WebsiteUrl;
        public string HtmlCode;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string formated = string.Format("{0}\n---------------------------------- \n{1}", WebsiteUrl, HtmlCode);
            return formated;
        }
    }
}
```

In the method

```
        private static void addPerson(string websiteUrl)
        {
            dict.Add(websiteUrl, new WebsiteInfo { WebsiteUrl = websiteUrl, HtmlCode = getHtml(websiteUrl) });
        }
```

the `HtmlCode = getHtml(websiteUrl`) is throwing an error:

```
"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HtmlCheck.Program.getHtml(string)'"
```

So my question is, why cant I add an entry to the dictionary with this information?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: getHtml is not a static method. So you would need to construct a Program object to call it on. I think you just want to add static keyword to that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addPerson()` is a **static** method, which means you can call it any time, without having an instance of the class to call it on. It then tries to call `getHtml()`, which is **non-static**, which means it can only be called through a valid instance of the class.

I suggest you do some research on static methods in C# to get your head around this.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting that error because `addPerson()` is a static method (it is called without creating an instance of the `Program` class), but the `getHtml()` method is *not* static (so you need an instance of the `Program` class to call it).

Easy fix - make it static too:

```
public static string getHtml(string websiteUrl)
{
    ...
}
```

For the sake of completeness, you'd have to otherwise create an instance of the `Program` class before calling the `getHtml()` method:

```
private static void addPerson(string websiteUrl)
{
    var p = new Program();
    dict.Add(websiteUrl, new WebsiteInfo { WebsiteUrl = websiteUrl, HtmlCode = p.getHtml(websiteUrl) });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "static" to your method;

```
        public static string getHtml(string websiteUrl)
```